# Can two s3cmd put commands run concurrently without adverse results?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, corruption, s3cmd

Can two s3cmd put commands[1] run concurrently to the same AWS/S3 bucket - without adverse reprocussions[2]?

---

[1] Say, one runs manually, and then one from crontab joins.
[2] E.g., file corruption on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 can handle plenty of concurrent connections. You won't have a problem.

The only contention might be for your bandwidth to S3.